# Integral $\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-a^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, complex-integration

I was just solving a question of integration which though I know how to solve but just thought of approaching it in a different way which includes use of complex numbers.

> **Question:-** $\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-a^2}}dx}$

---

**Standard Approach:-**
Let $z=e^x\implies dz=e^xdx$

So, the integral becomes $\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z^2-a^2}}}=\ln\left|z+\sqrt{z^2-a^2}\right|+c=\ln\left|e^x+\sqrt{e^{2x}-a^2}\right|+c$

---

**The approach through which I am trying to solve the question:-**

Let $z=e^x\implies dz=e^xdx$

$\therefore \displaystyle\int{\dfrac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-a^2}}dx}=\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{dz}{\sqrt{z^2-a^2}}}=\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{\sqrt{-1}dz}{\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{z^2-a^2}}}=\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{idz}{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}}}$

Now form this point I thought that there can be two routes which can be followed to arrive at an answer but none being the answer.

**First Route:-**
Let $y=iz\implies dy=idz$

Then $\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{idz}{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}}}=\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{a^2+y^2}}}=\ln\left|y+\sqrt{y^2+a^2}\right|=\ln\left|iz+\sqrt{a^2-z^2}\right|+c$

**Second Route:-**$\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{idz}{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}}}=i\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{dz}{\sqrt{a^2-z^2}}}=i\sin^{-1}{\dfrac{x}{a}}+c$

---

So, what am I doing wrong here, and also I do not have much knowledge of complex integration so is it a basic conceptual mistake that I am making because of treating $i$ as a constant.

Comment: You do not seem to be doing anything wrong. All of the expressions are equivalent. Since $\arcsin(z) = -i\ln(iz-\sqrt{1-z^2})$, we have $i\arcsin(\frac{z}{a}) + c= \ln(iz-\sqrt{a^2-z^2}) + (c - \ln(a))$. Plugging in $z = e^x$ would then yield $\ln(e^x+\sqrt{e^{2x}-a^2)}) + (c+ \ln(i))$